# Missing APIs & auth > Registered apps in Google cloud console / How do I obtain GCM API key?

Tags: android, google-play-services

This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670736/i-didnt-find-apis-auth-registered-apps-in-google-cloud-console) and is closed as "off - topic". I didn't see any stackexchange network sites for asking this question so I am re-asking here. I know this is very confusing problems for beginner. 
I was trying to use Google cloud messaging service. I had followed the official android developer [guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html). I had performed all the steps as mention there but got stuck at a point where it says "In the sidebar on the left, select **APIs & auth > Registered apps**." I looked at left side bar but couldn't find it. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that Google has not updated their documentation. In latest interface of Google Cloud Console, there is no any "Registered apps" menu under APIs and auth. You can do the same thing by selecting "Credentials" under "APIs and auth". After selecting "Credentials", click "CREATE NEW KEY" and choose the key you want to generate [image]
For the Google Cloud Messaging, click "Server Key" and provide the list of IPs from which it accepts the request. [If you do not provide any ip, then it allows any ip but this may create security issues]

**Update**: Finally Google has updated its documentation.

Comment: Weird google still has not updated this tutorial  https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/java
I just checked a few minutes ago.

Comment: This one's not updated either: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/prediction_service_accounts

Answer (score 0):

I've just figure it out
In Google Cloud Platform when you are already inside your project, click to return on the dashboard, after you will see the section API in that section, there is a link at the bottom allowing you the see the overview of the APIs click on that link and now you can manage youra apis

Answer (score -1):

The Google Cloud Console interface seems to be updated again. For latest documentation you can refer to [this link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158857?hl=en).