# Missing Origin > APIs & Auth > Registered Apps in Google Cloud Console / How do I set an origin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-oauth, google-hangouts

My problem is that I cannot set the origin, which according to now-inaccurate [Google+ Ruby docs](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/ruby):

(As noted here, [Google's documentation no longer reflects how to register apps with its new UX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948510/missing-apis-auth-registered-apps-in-google-cloud-console-how-do-i-obtain).)

> Register the origins where your app is allowed to access the Google APIs. The origin is the unique combination of protocol, hostname, and port. You can enter multiple origins to allow for your app to run on different protocols, domains or subdomains. Wildcards are not allowed.
>
> Expand the OAuth 2.0 Client ID section.
>   In the Web origin field, enter your origin: `http://localhost:4567`
>   Press ENTER to save your origin. You can then click the + symbol to add additional origins.

I need to set the origin because while using [Instant Hangouts](https://github.com/google/instant-hangouts), part of the url requested through the Google+ API is the parameter origin which fails with port 3000 and my public site, but succeeds with port 8080 (i.e. `localhost:8080/`). My challenge is how to validate an origin, although I don't see how to do that with the current UX of Google Cloud Console.

Does anybody have experience with setting the origin manually or recently?

Thanks

Other Details:
+ Only need public access, no need for OAUTH
+ However I'm willing to do what's necessary to get a validated origin

Answer (score 1):

Go to [cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com/console/project), select the specific project name, click on *APIs & auth* => *credentials* and then *edit settings* under *Client ID for web application* or *create new client ID* if there is no  client ID yet.